# Setting MacOS Airport Utility into monitoring multiple channels

Tags: wireless-networking, mac, wireshark, airport

I am using MacBook Pro 14' 2021 M1 Pro with MacOS Ventura 13.3.1. I would like to use wireshark in monitor mode with wifi interface. I have read, that I can switch 802.11 channels with the command:

```sh
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/A/Resources/airport -c<channel_no>
```

Is there an option to hear to all channel simultaneously?
I am new to WiFi protocols. Could you explain channels and interface's ability to hear to them?

Comment: This would require having multiple comm radios.

Comment: Think of it as like trying to watch two TV shows at the same time. You'd need 2 tuners or cable boxes. [Many cable boxes these days do actually have multi-channel capability, watch one, record 6 others at once… but they're built like that. Your Mac isn't.]

Comment: So I would have to buy some USB wifi interface, which is capable of multichannel capturing?